# Change Folder Permissons in Debian

Tags: debian, permissions

I have some folders with account/user  "**OpenERP**" and i created new folder (web_theme) under this directory .
When i try to open/read this folder (web_theme) it throws "**Do not have the Permissions**"

I have pointed new folder is in root

```
drwxrwxr-x 7 openerp openerp 4096 Oct  7 10:25 web
drwxrwxr-x 4 openerp openerp 4096 Oct  7 10:30 web_calendar
drwxrwxr-x 4 openerp openerp 4096 Oct  7 10:30 web_rpc
drwxrwxr-x 4 openerp openerp 4096 Oct  7 10:30 web_tests
drwx------ 4 root    root    4096 Oct 18 02:42 web_theme
```

Tried below commands

```
su/sudo chmod -R 0770 web_theme
chmod -R 0755 web_theme
chmod 666 web_theme
```

It Throws Error:

```
chmod: changing permissions of `web_theme': Operation not permitted
chmod: cannot read directory `web_theme': Permission denied
```

How do i resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an addon to cbliard's answer:

if you find the numeric notation of permissions a bit tedious, you can also use a symbolic form (which i find easier to read).
the following will allow **a**ll users (that is: the **o**wner of the file, it's **g**roup and all **o**thers) to both **r**ead all files/directories within `web_theme` and to e**x**ecute these files/directories. the capital **X** will make sure that only those files/dirs are marked executable that are already executable "for some user". in practice this means that it will mark directories as "executable" (which is needed to traverse them), but not ordinary files:

```
 chmod -R a+rX web_theme
```

as cbliard has stated you have to be superuser (`root`) or the owner of the files/directories (in this case this is also `root`) to run this command. since `sudo` seems to be forbidden for this particular task on your machine, try something like:

```
 openerp@vv:~$ cd ~/instances/openerp/webclient/addons/web_theme
 openerp@vv:...$ su
 root@vv:...# chmod -R a+rX
```

Comment: @Selvi rather than adding a "thanks" comment, you might *upvote* questions that were helpful and *accept* the answer you found best.

Answer (score 4):

You were close. Try

```
sudo chmod -R 0755 web_theme
```

As root own the file, it must be root who runs `chmod`, so you have to use `sudo`

About your tries:

- `sudo chmod -R 0770 web_theme` allows root user and root group to read the directory, but other user do not have any permission
- `chmod -R 0755 web_theme` does not work because only the file owner (root) can change permissions, thus the `chmod: changing permissions of`web_theme': Operation not permitted`
- `chmod 666 web_theme` does not work because only the file owner (root) can change permissions, but even without that, if the execute permission was missing (`0666`) then you would not be allowed to search into the directory. You would have to use `0777`, but this is too permissive as you give write permission. The best is to give `0755` permission: root can read/write/search, other can read/search.

Comment: openerp@vv:~/instances/openerp/webclient/addons$ sudo chmod -R 0755 web_theme
Sorry, user openerp is not allowed to execute '/bin/chmod -R 0755 web_theme' as root on vv.

Comment: Login as your own user or root user and try again.

Comment: Thank You. It Works like                   openerp@vv:~/instances/openerp/webclient$ su 
Password: 
root@vv:/instances/openerp/webclient# chmod -R 0755 addons/web_theme ..